# In Azure Cognitive Search how do you match on fields with a hyphen in it?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Using Azure Search I want to make it possible for people to find files that match their input, even if they forget a hyphen '-' or substitute it with a space ' '.

For example I have a document with in it the following: "F-150".
I want the search to return results on the following searches: "F-150", "F150" and "F 150".

By default Azure Search will match with "F-150" and "F 150" since it sees the hyphen '-' as a split in the term just like a space. But it does not match on the combined term "F150".

To counter this is added a charfilter to the search that replaces the hyphen with nothing.

```
"charFilters": [
 {
   "name":"replace hyphen character",
   "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
   "mappings":["-=>"]
 }
]
```

After using this it now does match on the "F150" term and still on "F-150" but now it does not match on the "F 150" anymore.

I also tried adding this filter to try and replace the space:

```
{
      "name":"replace space character",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
      "mappings":["\\u0020=>"]
}
```

But that does not seem to help in anyway.

So now I am stuck on what to do, and wondering if there is a solution to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

So I create 2 new field called "ModelEdited" and "TypeEdited" that have the same settings as the "Model" and "Type" fields except that these edited fields use "replace hyphen" as analyzer. That works.

```
"fieldMappings":[
      { "sourceFieldName" : "Model", "targetFieldName" : "ModelEdited" },
      { "sourceFieldName" : "Type", "targetFieldName" : "Typedited" }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to solve it using only one field, you can create a second field as a copy of the original field where you can use the default analyzer. Then, when searching you'll do it in both fields.

Comment: Good idea, I was also thinking about doing it that way. But could not really find a way to copy a term in Azure Search without changing my data. Is it somehow possible to achieve this without changing the document in the search?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to change anything in your data, just use a different analyzer

Comment: I've tried something like this, I updated my answer with the things I tried. Now I get an error trying to create the index.